Necessity of the closedness assumption in the definition of (definable) Whitney stratification
In, the paper Geometric categories and o-minimal structures by Van Den Dries and Miller, the definition of a Whitney stratification of a function is given for a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, with $A$ a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
In particular, in 4.8 it is proven that if $f$ is definable in an o-minimal structure on $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$, again, with  $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, with $A$ a closed, then it admits a Whitney $C^p$ stratification, compatible with any finite collections of definable sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I was wondering if the fact that $A$ is closed is important?
To me, in the definable world, if $A$ is not closed, then we can arbitrary extend $f$ to $\overline{A}$ and take a stratification adapted to $\{A, \overline{A} \backslash A \}$.
Perhaps, the closedness assumption has to do with the fact that a major part of the paper is dealing with geometric-analytic categories (with which i am not familiar). But I would greatly appreciate a confirmation (or infirmation) of this fact.
